# Appropriate way to add progress circle in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, progress

I am using AngularJS. I have a function in my controller that gets `.json` file from the server, working with data and store it in `$scope`.
So basically this function needs biggest amount of time when the page is loading.

So I have something like this, my page has loaded but but my table (that populates with `ng-repeat`) has not. It takes few seconds to load the table. And while the table is loading I want to add progress circle like that:

[image]

**What is appropriate way to do it in AngularJS?**

Here is a controller demo:

```
 var serverData = $http.get('data/topCarObj.json');
 function sortCars(){
    angular.forEach($scope.tabArray, function(tab){
        serverData.success(function(data){
            angular.forEach(data, function(key){
                ....
                return myCarList;
            });
        });
     });
}
```

Comment: Where is actual request code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Controller:

```
$scope.getData = function() {    // wrap a data getting code in a function
        $scope.loading = true;     // define a variable that indicate the loading status   // true here
        $http.get('path_to_json').success(function (data) {   // get the data 
            $scope.loading = false;     // loading is finished so loading = false
        })
        .error(function (data, status) {
             $scope.loading = false;    // loading = false when there is a error
        });
}

$scope.getData();         // call the function to get data
```

In View:

```
<img src="loading.gif" ng-show="loading" /> // show the loading.gif when `$scope.loading` variable is `true`
```

Comment: my gif progress circle image is not moving when the page is loading only when it is loaded.

Comment: image shows when data is loading. if you want to show the image for page loading also you can put `$scope.loading = true;` top of the `$scope.getData` function :)

Answer (score 1):

In your controller set `$scope.doneLoading = true` after all data is received and processed.

In your view have the animated image show with `ng-if='!doneLoading'` and hide other components with a similar, negated condition.

Alternatively you could also have a global throbber that is controlled by a watch on `$http.pendingRequests` - but unfortunately the docs say about pendingRequests that "This is primarily meant to be used for debugging purposes."

Also from a usability view I would prefer showing a throbber only at those parts of the view that are actually currently loading.