# Show progress circular during $http post?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

What is the best way to use Angular Material's [Progress circular](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.progressCircular) component  with a `$http` request?

I currently have the code like this below:

Progress circular:

```
<md-progress-circular ng-if="determinateValue === 100" md-mode="determinate" value="{{determinateValue}}"></md-progress-circular>
```

`$http` request:

```
$scope.determinateValue = 0;

$http.get("/posts")
       .success(function (data) {

          $scope.posts = data;
          $scope.determinateValue = 100;

       })
```

Comment: this may helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116281/appropriate-way-to-add-progress-circle-in-angularjs/26116360#26116360

Comment: It needs to be a number  https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/api/material.components.progressCircular/directive/mdProgressCircular

Comment: ok then put `$scope.loading = 1;` and `$scope.loading = 0;` this also will treat as booleans `true` and `false`

Comment: It expects you to go all the way up to 100? Having ```$scope.loading = 1;``` is going to keep it at the start https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.progressCircular

Comment: The problem is that you don't seem to have numbers for this task. If it were multiple AJAX calls, you could add them up to a percentage, but a single AJAX call at this abstraction is pretty binary (0 at start, 100 at end, no events or numbers in the middle). Instead, you probably want "Indeterminate" mode for this particular event.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think you need the `value` attribute here with `determinate` mode. Instead you should use `indeterminate` mode, then show and hide the progress indicator using `ngShow`.

```
<md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" ng-show="isLoading"></md-progress-circular>
```

And in your JS

```
$scope.isLoading = true;
$http.get("/posts")
   .success(function (data) {
        $scope.isLoading = false;
   });
```

Comment: `isLoading` should be set `true` before the request, `false` after, since that's when it's loading. If you change the variable to `isLoaded` or `hasLoaded` the current true/false makes sense. Also, and this relates more to the original question, it should probably be in `finally` to prevent the loading indicator from spinning forever on error.

Comment: Great this will do, it makes sense when reading this ```For operations where the user is asked to wait a moment while something finishes up, and it's not necessary to expose what's happening behind the scenes and how long it will take, use an indeterminate indicator.```

Comment: @MichaelWilson Ditto :')

Comment: how to make `spinner` inline / inline-block

Answer (score 20):

If you want a version of md-progress-circular that also inhibits the screen and has a backdrop place the md-progress-circular inside an mdDialog like this:

```
     function showWait(){
          $mdDialog.show({
            controller: 'waitCtrl',
            template: '<md-dialog style="background-color:transparent;box-shadow:none">' +
                        '<div layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center center" aria-label="wait">' +
                            '<md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" ></md-progress-circular>' +
                        '</div>' +
                     '</md-dialog>',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            clickOutsideToClose:false,
            fullscreen: false
          })
          .then(function(answer) {

          });
   }
```

here is a plunker i created that shows how
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/wY3jP9D4Vd9mcu6EYIQC)

Comment: This is exactly what I need.  Thank you so much. All of the examples   That I have seen place the progress  indicator in line and cause other elements to move around when the progress is activate and deactivated.  That would not work for me.  This does.  Good job.

Answer (score 2):

All answers are right just add one more thing that  `$http` request is asynchronous you should use like this

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
$scope.isLoading = false;
});
```

And as whole like this

```
<md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" ng-show="isLoading"></md-progress-circular>
```

And in your JS

$scope.isLoading = true;

```
$http.get("/posts")
   .success(function (data) {
         $scope.$apply(function(){
           $scope.isLoading = false;
         });
   });
```

**Note:-** Source of the answer is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should hook up to `$httpProvider`'s events:

```
angular.module('common')
  .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$rootScope', '$q', '$timeout',
      function($rootScope, $q, $timeout) {
        return {
          request: function(config) {
            $rootScope.posting = new Date().getTime();
            $rootScope.$broadcast('$postingStart', config.url);
            return $q.resolve(config);
          },
          response: function(response) {
            $rootScope.posting = false;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('$postingEnd', response.config.url);
            return $q.resolve(response);
          },
          responseError: function(response) {
            $rootScope.posting = false;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('$postingEnd', response.config.url);
            return $q.reject(response);
          }
        };
      }]);
  }])
.run(['$mdDialog', '$rootScope', function($mdDialog, $rootScope){
  var showing = false;

  function showWait() {
    if(showing) return;
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: 'waitCtrl',
      template: '<md-dialog id="plz_wait" style="background-color:transparent;box-shadow:none">' +
      '<div layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center center" aria-label="wait">' +
      '<md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" ></md-progress-circular>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</md-dialog>',
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      clickOutsideToClose: false,
      fullscreen: false
    })
      .then(function(answer) {
        showing = false;
      });
  }


  $rootScope.$on('$postingStart', function(event, url) {
    if (!$rootScope.postingStartTimer) {
      $rootScope.postingStartTimer = $timeout(function() {
        showWait()
      }, 250);
    }
  });

  $rootScope.$on('$postingEnd', function(event, url) {
    if ($rootScope.postingStartTimer && posts.length === 0) {
      $timeout.cancel($rootScope.postingStartTimer);
      $rootScope.postingStartTimer = false;
      if(!showing) return;
      $mdDialog.cancel();
    }
  });

}])
```

Comment: I tried this version, which looks good, but $timeout was missing and it says `posts` is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this code helps.

```
  var isLoadingShown = false;

  $scope.$watch(function() {
    return $http.pendingRequests.length;
  }, 
  function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    if(newValue !== 0) {
      if(!isLoadingShown) {
        showLoading();         
      }
    }
    else hideLoading();
  });

  function showLoading(){
    isLoadingShown = true;   
    $mdDialog.show({
      template: '<md-dialog style="background-color:transparent;box-shadow:none;overflow: hidden !important;">' +
                  '<div layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center center" aria-label="wait">' +
                    '<md-progress-circular class="md-hue-2" md-diameter="50px"></md-progress-circular>' +
                  '</div>' +
                '</md-dialog>',
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      clickOutsideToClose:false,
      escapeToClose: false,
      fullscreen: false
    });
  }

  function hideLoading(){
    $mdDialog.cancel();
    isLoadingShown = false; 
  }
```

Comment: it's really nice, but pressing ESC cancels the dialog, so you should add also 'escapeToClose: false' to the mdDialog configuration

Comment: Thanks @DoruChiulan . i added.

Answer (score 0):

First set some model:

```
$scope.loading=false;
```

Bind that model with progress circular element ng-show property:

```
<md-progress-circular ng-show="loading" md-mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-circular>
```

Set it to true before calling $http request and set it to false on $http .success:

```
$scope.loading=true;

$http.get("/posts")
   .success(function (data) {

      $scope.posts = data;

      $scope.loading=false;

   })
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Doesn't progress circular need to be a number? https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/api/material.components.progressCircular/directive/mdProgressCircular

Comment: I've edited my answer. ng-show will affect only visibility of the html element (true -visible, false - hidden). Assign value to  $scope.determinateValue in $http success callback before calling loading=false and you are good to go.

Comment: According to documentation you don't need determinate mode in md-progress-circular. Just put it to indeterminate. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to watch the progress of post data use [uploadEventHandlers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

There is an example.

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/uploadToFtp',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': undefined
    },
    eventHandlers: {
        progress: function(c) {
            //console.log('Progress -> ' + c);
            //console.log(c);
        }
    },
    uploadEventHandlers: {
        progress: function(e) {
            //console.log('UploadProgress -> ' + e);
            //console.log(e);
            _self.progressValue = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100.0;
        }
    },
    data: postData,
    transformRequest: angular.identity
})
.then(callBack,errorCallBack)
.catch(errorCallBack);
```

Show the progress circular like this

```
<md-progress-circular ng-if="ctrl.progressValue > 0 && ctrl.progressValue < 100" md-mode="determinate" value="{{ctrl.progressValue}}"></md-progress-circular>
```