# how to show progress circular in angularjs single page application

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-material

I want to use progress circular in my SPA(single page application) and i done it but there was an issue that the shape of circle is showing worse.

> For clear understanding i provide an image of circular which was showing in my application.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG8kT.png)
>
> but i don't understand why the shape of this is showing worse, i don't know, please help me to come out from this problem.

Comment: Please visit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101207/show-progress-circular-during-http-post

Comment: @NarottamMakvana there is no solution of my problem, have you read my question or not

Comment: Please provide a code for better help. Thanks.

Comment: @Rock here is my code:-                  <div layout = "row" layout-sm = "column" layout-align = "center center" class="circular-progress-button">
                        <md-progress-circular md-mode = "indeterminate" md-diameter="200"></md-progress-circular>
                    </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found my soulution

> a css file in my html file is conflict with the angular js material css file.
>   so, when i remove that file then everything is perfect.